# Accessing an attribute of a foreignkey field in a django model

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a model method that returns an attribute of a foreign key. In this case, I want get_place_name() to return the pretty_name field of the place model. But when I do so, I get an attribute error: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pretty_name'"

```
class CalendarEvent(models.Model):

    event_id = models.CharField( max_length=22, db_index=True, unique=True )
    event_name = models.CharField( max_length=255, db_index=True )
    place = models.ForeignKey( Place, blank=True, null=True  )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.event_name

    def get_place_name(self):
        return "%s" % self.place.pretty_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have `null=True` for your `place` foreign key. Is it possible that for the particular `CalendarEvent` that you are calling, `place` is indeed `None`?  In which case the error would be accurate.  You could handle that more gracefully by modifying your `get_place_name` method:

```
def get_place_name(self):
    if self.place:
        return self.place.pretty_name
```